# Deleting row on Foreign key relation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table on which I have a foreign key constraint like below

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Element] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Element_Band] 
    FOREIGN KEY([BandID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Band] ([BandID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Element] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Element_Band]
GO
```

Now I am trying to delete a row from the band table like this

```
DELETE FROM Band 
WHERE TypeID = 21 AND BandUpperLimit = 10000 AND PID = 61
```

But I am getting a reference constraint error:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Element_Band". The conflict occurred in database "pricingModified", table "dbo.Element", column 'BandID'.

So this should happen if I have anything in the `Elements` table which is referencing `Band` table with the ID 21 but that's not the case since the SQL

```
SELECT * 
FROM Element 
WHERE BandID = 21
```

returns nothing.

Can someone please tell me why I am not able to delete row data from the parent table even though there is no reference present in the child table?

Thanks

Comment: You are checking `TypeID` in `Band` but `BandID` in `Element`. Typo? I think you were about to delete a lot more `Band` records than you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Just specify ON DELETE CASCADE in your foreign key constraint.  Then when you delete a row from the Band table it will automatically delete any child records in the Element table.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Element] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Element_Band] 
    FOREIGN KEY([BandID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Band] ([BandID]) ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Check with this query instead:

```
select b.* 
from Element e
  inner join Band b 
    on e.BandId = b.BandId
where b.TypeId = 21
  and b.BandUpperLimit = 10000 
  and b.PID = 61
```

Answer (score 0):

while creating child table

```
create table <child_table_name>  
(  
_______,  
_______,  
([FOREIGN KEY column_name]) [size of FOREIGN KEY column] references [parent table(primary key column_name)] on delete cascade  
)
```

Using this you can easily delete record of fk using delete operation..
Try this, if it is successful then mark it positive...